# Adding variable amount of tspan elements to text depending on d attribute in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

```
var spans = {};
    var counter = 0;
    var f = 0;
    labelT.each(function(d,i){
            var splitted = d.name.split(" ");
            console.log(splitted);
            for(var k = 0,f = 0; k < splitted.length; k++,f += 1.2){
                spans[k] = labelT.select(this).append("tspan")
                .attr("class", "tspan"+counter)
                .attr("dy",f+"em")
                .attr("x",0)
                .text(function(d){return splitted[k]});
                counter ++ ;
            }
            counter ++;
    });
```

I want to add as many tspans to the labelT var which is a text element in dependence of how many words are in the var array splitted. This should result in a new line for each word. the problem is, that I have no idea how to select current labelT element. I tried alread labelT.select in the for loop and and the posted version of selection. can anyone help? 
thanks!

Comment: d3.select(this).append ...... solved the problem and got the right selection.

Comment: If you write this as an answer (preferably with a good explanation) you can accept it (OPs can accept their own answers after a couple of days).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the above solution does work, you should be able to re-bind the data to the element using a "more-D3-style" solution. Please note that I haven't tested this code, so you might need to fiddle with it to get it 100% working:

```
labelT.each(function each(d,i) {
    var split = d.name.split(' ');

    d3.select(this)
        .data(split)
        .enter()
        .append('tspan')
        .attr('class', function setAttr(d, i) { return 'tspan' + i; })
        .attr('dy', function setAttr(d, i) { return (i * 1.2) + 'em'; })
        .attr('x', 0)
        .text(function setText(d) { return d; });
});
```

Comment: thanks for that, the re-bind is pretty nice and clever! 
the only line which doesn't fit to my problem is:

.attr('dy', function setAttr(d, i) { return (i * 1.2) + 'em'; })

I stick with:
.attr("dy",f+"em") because this does excactly one line break after each tspan